# Ionic QRCodeScanner is not being imported

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, qr-code

I'm trying to use the QRCodeScanner from Ionic. But when I try to compile it gives me these errors:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ionic-native/qr-scanner/index.js 286:8-15
"export 'Cordova' was not found in '@ionic-native/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ionic-native/qr-scanner/index.js 294:8-15
"export 'Cordova' was not found in '@ionic-native/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ionic-native/qr-scanner/index.js 304:8-15
"export 'Cordova' was not found in '@ionic-native/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ionic-native/qr-scanner/index.js 310:8-15
"export 'Cordova' was not found in '@ionic-native/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ionic-native/qr-scanner/index.js 316:8-15
"export 'Cordova' was not found in '@ionic-native/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ionic-native/qr-scanner/index.js 324:8-15
"export 'Cordova' was not found in '@ionic-native/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ionic-native/qr-scanner/index.js 330:8-15
"export 'Cordova' was not found in '@ionic-native/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ionic-native/qr-scanner/index.js 338:8-15
"export 'Cordova' was not found in '@ionic-native/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ionic-native/qr-scanner/index.js 346:8-15
"export 'Cordova' was not found in '@ionic-native/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ionic-native/qr-scanner/index.js 354:8-15
"export 'Cordova' was not found in '@ionic-native/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ionic-native/qr-scanner/index.js 362:8-15
"export 'Cordova' was not found in '@ionic-native/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ionic-native/qr-scanner/index.js 368:8-15
"export 'Cordova' was not found in '@ionic-native/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ionic-native/qr-scanner/index.js 374:8-15
"export 'Cordova' was not found in '@ionic-native/core'
```

My app.module:

```
...
import { QRScanner } from '@ionic-native/qr-scanner';
...
providers:[
    MovementExecutionService,
    VacancyService,
    MovementTableUtil,
    QRScanner
  ],
```

package.json:

```
"@ionic-native/qr-scanner": "^4.20.0",
```

What am I missing?

Comment: which ionic version are you using??

Check this link https://ionicframework.jp/docs/native/qr-scanner

Comment: I'm using 5.36v

Comment: try with this import { QRScanner, QRScannerStatus } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/qr-scanner/ngx';

Comment: Do you know if this qr-scanner works only in ionic 6?

Comment: not its working in ionic 5 also and 6

Comment: Correcting my ionic version is 4.11

Comment: Check this link here is full example "https://enappd.com/blog/ionic-4-qr-code-barcode-scanning/82/"